# How to convert objects to curves? | Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

**Question**: How to convert objects to curves?

---

I found this seemingly very useful tool in a different editor call Affinity Designer ([here](https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/index.html?page=pages/ObjectControl/converttocurves.html?title=Converting%20objects%20to%20curves)) and wanted to see if Inkscape has something similar.

Basically, it allows you to set custom points for shapes:

[example](https://coinsh.red/u/converttocurves.png)

Answer (score 1):

This same operation in Inkscape is called *Convert to Path*, and can be found under the *Path* menu.

Documentation [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths.html).